# AngularJS : $index-ing same items in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat` like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in items"
  {{item.name}} {{$index}}
```

If I have the following items:

```
[{
  name: "House"
},{
  name: "House"
},
{
  name: "City"
}]
```

The result of `ng-repeat` will be

```
House 0
House 1
City  2
```

I need it to be:

```
House 0
House 1
City  0
```

So that if I have 3 items with same name "House" and 5 items with same name "City", the result would be:

```
House 0
House 1
House 2
City  0
City  1
City  2
City  3
City  4
```

How can I do that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an object containing a set of counters and doing something like

In your controller:

```
$scope.counters = {};
//initialize $scope.counters[name] to 0 for each of your distinct names
```

In your view:

```
ng-repeat="item in items"
    {{item.name}} {{counters[item.name]++}}
```

Comment: @Raibaz What if the items are dynamically added, removed, updated ?

Comment: I guess in that case you have to separately update the counters